# Infinite $3$-chromatic hypergraphs

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, graph-colorings, hypergraph, infinite-combinatorics

Let $H=(V,E)$ be a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph). If $\kappa>0$ is a cardinal, we say the hypergraph $H$ is $\kappa$-*chromatic* if there is a function $c:V\to\kappa$  such that for all $e\in E$ the restriction $c|_e$ is not constant (that is, the vertices of every edge are colored with at least $2$ colors).

We say that $H$ is a *clique hypergraph* if for all $e,f \in E$ we have $e\cap f \neq \emptyset$ and we call $H$  $\kappa$-*regular* for some cardinal $\kappa$, if $|e| = \kappa$ for all $e\in E$.

**Question**. If $\kappa \geq \aleph_0$ and $H=(V,E)$ is a $\kappa$-regular clique hypergraph that is $3$-chromatic, but not $2$-chromatic, are there $e\neq f\in E$ such that $|e\cap f| = \kappa$?

Comment: If we manage to well-order all edges so that each edge has less than $\kappa$ vertices of all previous edges, we may colour by transfinite induction.

Comment: The question of whether such a well-ordering is always possible could be a nice MO problem in its own right!

Comment: I think this is relevant:  P. Erdős, S. Shelah: Separability properties of almost-disjoint families of sets, Israel J. Math. 12 (1972), 207--214 http://www.renyi.mta.hu/~p_erdos/1972-21.pdf